# Why do I get error with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.6

I used a piece of code I found on the forum to avoid several audio files to be played simultaneously on one page.

```
   document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
    }, true);
```

It works perfect on a test html page, bt I got an error when I tried to integrate it to my Prestashop website.

> 'libreecoute.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function'

Comment: What is your `$`, is that jQuery? jQuery objects do not have an `addEventListener` method

Comment: Replace `$(...)` with a proper `querySelector`, which allows you to use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up DOM objects with jQuery objects.

Comment: How does that code above fire that error?

Comment: Your snippet is fine as above stated, you need to look elsewhere in the code for the jquery object you need to replace with a dom node or assuming its jquery replace with an on() method

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use `addEventListener` (which is vanilla JS) on a jQuery stuff...

Try the *javascript way* with `document.querySelectorAll()/getElementById()/etc...` +`addEventListener()` **or** adapt your code to use the *jquery way* with the   [*on* method](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks !
Indeed it seems I made a mix...
I seems "on method" is the right way , but first I have to understand how it works and how to adapt my code.
Thanks for the clue!